# Question about proof that multiplication in Banach algebra is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Here's the proof in my notes:
[image]

Where does the last inequality come from? If I want to show that it's continuous at $((x,y)$ I can use the inverse triangle inequality to get 
$$ (\|x^\prime\| + \|y\|)\varepsilon \leq (\|x\| + \|y \| + \varepsilon)\varepsilon$$

Thanks.

Comment: maybe its a typo, maybe he just felt like writing $1$ rather than $\epsilon$, since it doesn't really make a diference. I don't see how this is important.

Comment: I agree with h.h.543. The author even said $\epsilon<1$!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\varepsilon<1$, 
$$\color{red}{\lVert x'\rVert}+\lVert y\rVert\leq \color{red}{\lVert x'-x\rVert+\lVert x\rVert} +\lVert y\rVert\leq\color{red}{\varepsilon}+\lVert x\rVert+\lVert y\rVert\leq \color{red}{1}+\lVert x\rVert+\lVert y\rVert.$$

Comment: Thanks. May I ask a question which may be a bit off-topic? This proof shows that the multiplication is continuous with respect to the norm, without any reference to the norm condition $||xy||\le||x||||y||$ in the definition of normed algebra. So it means any algebra with a norm has continuous multiplication. Then my question is why do we need the norm condition in the definition of normed algebra ? I thought the norm condition is meant to make multiplication continuous.

Comment: @Hua, it is used to obtain the second inequality.

Answer (score 2):

It comes from the triangle inequality $$||x'||\leq ||x'-x||+||x||,$$
and the hypothesis $$||x'-x||\leq\varepsilon,\quad \varepsilon\in]0,1[$$

Answer (score 0):

As Davide said,

$(\|x^\prime\| + \|y\|)\varepsilon \leq (\|x\| + \|y \| + \varepsilon)\varepsilon \leq (\|x\| + \|y \| + 1)\varepsilon$, as $\varepsilon < 1$, hence the given inequality.